# Spring Tool Suite (STS)- cant update

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite, eclipse-luna

When i check for updates and i get this this error message:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Spring Tool Suite 3.6.1.201408250821-RELEASE-e37 
(org.springsource.sts.ide 3.6.1.201408250821-RELEASE-e37)
  Missing requirement: Spring Tool Suite Package 3.6.1.201408250821-RELEASE-e37 
(org.springsource.sts.package.feature.group 3.6.1.201408250821-RELEASE-e37) requires 
'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.7.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring Tool Suite 3.6.1.201408250821-RELEASE-e37 (org.springsource.sts.ide 
3.6.1.201408250821-RELEASE-e37)
    To: org.springsource.sts.package.feature.group [3.6.1.201408250821-RELEASE-e37]
```

sts version :

Version: 3.6.1.RELEASE
Build Id: 201408250818
Platform: Eclipse Luna (4.4)

system  :

ubuntu 14.04

Thanks,

Comment: What version of STS do you have installed at the moment? (STS version, Eclipse platform version)

Answer (score 2):

In my case following worked for STS on ubuntu-

1- go to your {user.home}/.eclipse/org.eclipse.oomph.p2/cache and clean all the cache

2- update STS (Help > About STS > Installation Details > Update)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Preferences/Install-Update/Available Software Sites and disable 'SpringSource Update Site for Eclipse 3.7'.

I have also raised an issue for this on the [STS Jira](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3910).

Martin

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks! But afterwards it told me that there's no update. I guess thats expected